# How to analyze a contingency table with time series?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, contingency-tables, ecology

I have a contingency table with frequency of food items (rows) measured across 10 years (columns). I wonder what kind of analysis I should use to model the variation in food frequencies with time (preferably in R). 
It is data of nesting gull-billed tern diet. It records the number of times a given prey is brought to a fixed colony. Food categories are bird, fish, frog, reptile, crustacean, insect, other invertebrate. Data is aggregated by year. Hypotheses: Do diet change over the years? If so, does it in a predictable pattern? (for instance monotonic increase of one item over others).

Comment: How many food items do you have? Maybe you can show us (part of) the table? Some more details and context, please. Animal (which) or human data? What is the goal of the analysis? Some ideas: Maybe [correspondence analysis](https://www.google.no/search?q=correspondence+analysis+with+a+time+series+of+contingency+tables&oq=correspondence+analysis+with+a+time+series+of+contingency+tables&aqs=chrome..69i57.19244j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? Multinomial logits with time as predictor? ...

Comment: It is data of nesting gull-billed tern diet. It records the number of times a given prey is brought to a fixed colony. Food categories are bird, fish, frog, reptile, crustacean, insect, other invertebrate. Data is aggregated by year. Hypotheses: Do diet change over the years? If so, does it in a predictable pattern? (for instance monotonic increase of one item over others). Tusen takk for hjelpen!

Comment: Can you please add that information as an edit to the original question? Then more people will see it. Gracias! Es datos de España, donde alla hay colonias de sandterne?

Comment: Here: 39º20'N 00º22W. It is a common summer visitor